# Special words in soccer

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

I would like to know a couple of words so special about soccer even Google can't help me.

1. What is the "gate" called (if you make the score, you kick the ball into the "gate". We call it "gate" (maybe door or front door) in Hungarian language. Maybe "net" or "goal" in English? Which is the right word?
2. What do you say if somebody makes a score? (We say "He made a goal", "kicked in the goal", "kicked the ball into the gate", etc., but we rarely say "he made a score", because scores are for the final standing of the match, so teams make scores (0, 1 or 3) not players.
3. We have the word *labdabiztosság* which is a special word in soccer to show the player's ability to be able to secure the ball and not lose it against the enemy easily. If somebody is *labdabiztos* it means he is not easy to dodge and have the ball taken away from him, so the ball is "secured" for his team. The literal translation is "ball security" (e.g. "This player is ball-secure".), but I don't think that's the phrase I'm looking for.
4. Another word is *gólveszélyes* which means "how dangerous this player is for making a score, what the chance is that this player makes the score if he is in the right position (in front of the 'net')". Word-for-word my best shot is "goal-dangerous" or "score-dangerous".

How do you say these soccer skills and phrases in English?

Comment: You should know that British and American English often have different words for the same thing. For a start, very few British fans refer to the game as soccer. For them it is football. Other examples: BE - extra time, AE - overtime; BE - pitch, AE - field. There are more differences at:  http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-22633980.

Comment: Shoe, that's a good point, considering that the sport in question is English and that in England and the rest of the UK, it is overwhelmingly known as **football**.

Comment: @Tristan No, Tristan: soccer is ***not*** inherently “an English sport”, as you put it.

Comment: tchrist, where do you think it comes from?

Comment: @Tristan China, of course.  But seriously, you have made perfectly clear that anything that somebody in North America says differently from the way you yourself say things bothers you. You don’t have to keep hammering away on the same old lament; it is tedious, petty, and immaterial.

Comment: tchrist, you could make an effort to read about the subject and learn about it. You may find it enlightening. As for what "bothers" me, I have not written anything about that.

Comment: @Walkman You can find more soccer terms [here](http://worldsoccer.about.com/od/soccer101/a/soccerglossary.htm), [here](http://www.socceramerica.com/glossary/), [here](http://www.juniorsoccercoach.com/public/730.cfm), [here](http://soccer.epicsports.com/soccer-glossary.html), [here](http://coachingamericansoccer.com/soccer-glossary/), [here](http://www.firstbasesports.com/soccer_glossary.html), and [here](http://www.soccer-for-parents.com/soccer-terms.html).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translating from another language into English.

Comment: @Shoe - Perhaps due to the popularity of the EPL in the USA, this is starting to change. For the most part, we in the USA are adopting the British terms for pretty much everything, with the possible exception of the game itself.

Comment: @T.E.D. Hopefully your managers (or coaches, as I think you call them) won't adopt some of the grammar to go along with the vocabulary. Then you'll be spared post-match analyses that include gems such as "_We was unlucky!_" or "_The boy done great!_"

Comment: @Shoe - The latter sounds like something the head coach for any American Football team in the SEC might say. At least your managers have an excuse, in that English is often their second language.

Answer (score 6):

1. 'Goal' is the correct word.
2. 'He scored a goal' or simply 'He scored'.
3. I don't believe there is an exactly equivalent single word in English. Such a player might possibly be described as 'strong', which also describes a player who stays on his feet in a tackle, or a player who pushes through the defence rather than going around them.
4. Again, there's no single word, though there are some clichés. 'Dangerous' is one word, similar to the Hungarian. Such a player might also be referred to as 'deadly' or, if he's known for keeping cool under pressure, 'clinical'.

Comment: I'd say that #1 could also be _net_, although _goal_ would be my primary choice. A referee might also talk about how the ball must _cross the plane_. As for #2, thanks to some rather infamous World Cup broadcasts in recent years, it's worth mentioning "Goooooooooooooooooooal!!" as an alternative. :^) Like you, I don't think there are exact translations for the last two. #3 could allude to _solid footwork_; if #4 is related to physical speed, there's always _he has wheels_, and likely other slang terms as well."

Comment: Are you sure English have no special word for noting a player more capable of scoring a goal than his teammates? Also why is "deadly" in this context? What's the meaning? Is "deadly" more a general term is somebody is better in something?

Comment: @Walkman: the New Oxford American Dictionary (NOAD), under its entry for _deadly_, reads: **(typically in the context of shooting or sports) extremely accurate, effective, or or skillful : _his aim is deadly_.**

Comment: Pretty sure. The level of skill regarding scoring goals is already denoted somewhat by the player's position. Isn't it obvious a striker is better at scoring goals than a defender? J.R. has answered your deadly question.

Comment: @J.R. I think this is the same as `gólveszélyes` (#4) not the same definition, but it describes exactly the skill I was looking for.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall There are strikers who are more deadly than others. How would you say that without the word "deadly"? :)
I don't think there is enough time to say this: "This striker is more capable of scoring than the other." in a live coverage.

Comment: I think you would simply say "A is better than B". Or you would use any other adjective that you might use to describe accuracy or ability. My point is there is no special word for describing football players specifically.

Comment: You can't say "A is better than B" if A is only more deadly in one skill (for example scoring when in front of Goal) but B is a better player overall, meaning player B is better for the team overall, but player A is more capable of scoring a goal.

Comment: To add to what Elendil just said, _dangerous_ is a word that's used not only in soccer, but all of sports. Baseball has [dangerous hitters](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22dangerous%20hitter%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1970,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en); American football has [dangerous receivers](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22dangerous%20receiver%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1970,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en); basketball and ice hockey have [dangerous shooters](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22dangerous%20shooter%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1970,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en), etc.

Comment: So, _Ed is a dangerous player_ would usually mean "Ed is more likely to score than his teammates," even though _Ed made a dangerous play_ would mean that Ed is about to receive a yellow (if not red) card. Incidentally, this conversation is probably better suited for ELL, the StackExchange for [ell.SE], in case you haven't seen that place yet.

Comment: Ok, then "dangerous" describes #4 best, and 'deadly' is an overall good rating for a player, right?
I didn't seen ELL yet, thanks for noticing.

Comment: "Deadly" would be one kind of overall good rating, but it makes sense mostly for offensive weapons ("He is a deadly shooter"). Ed might be a _deadly shooter_, but teammate Ted might be a _solid defender_, Ned a _skilled dribbler_, and Red an _uncannily accurate passer_. One other word you might consider is [freak](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77968/someone-with-special-athletic-skills/77975#77975), short for _freak of nature_, occasionally applied to players with raw athletic talent, such as [Abby Wambach](http://preps.gainesville.com/news/article/42145/a-to-z-with-eric-west/).

Answer (score 3):

This website should answer your questions: [Learning English Through Football](http://languagecaster.com/).

The following text is from the homepage:

> Welcome to the website that helps students interested in football
>   improve their English language skills. Soccer fans can enhance these
>   skills with lots of free language resources: a weekly podcast,
>   football phrases, explanations of football vocabulary, football
>   cliches, worksheets, quizzes and much more at languagecaster.com

Comment: Unfortunately, every link of this website is giving me a white blank page. :(

Comment: The pages take a long time to load, but the content is very good.

Comment: Link-only answers are really poor as answers. Could you please summarize the content?

Comment: @tchrist. The content is too voluminous to summarize, but I have edited my answer to include information from the website's homepage.

Answer (score 0):

The term "sniper" is used frequently by Canadian broadcasters to describe hockey players with a fast accurate shot on goal (or net). I think the term would transfer easily to an English-speaking soccer audience, though I don't follow soccer avidly enough to know if it is currently used. I believe that would meet your requirements for number 4.

Although it doesn't convert into a noun or adjective easily, a player who protects the ball/puck well for his team might be referred to "hoarding" it. However, perhaps because it is too similar sounding to "ball hog", I cannot imagine a player being referred to as a "ball hoarder", unless the inference was intended that this instinct was selfish and thus detrimental to the team.

Also, English-speaking sports broadcaster pride themselves on their ability to generate a fast stream of metaphors for describing the play-by-play as well as the players, in order to avoid repeating themselves. Alliterative metaphors are particularly popular, even when mildly ridiculous.

Consequently, I believe that almost any metaphor that you translate from another language will be accepted by English readers, and that you can use your choice of metaphors used by different speakers as a means of characterization for those speakers.

Comment: I tend to hear "sniper" used in soccer mostly to describe what happened to players who fall down for no apparent reason. :-)

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why? It seems an unusual use of the word.

Comment: Well, there has to be *some reason* that person fell down. Taken down by a sniper seems as good an explanation as any other.

Comment: Doesn't that confuse the agent and target?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet for learning all this would be to catch an English language broadcast for the Premiere League next season.

1. You are correct. "Goal" is most typical, but "net" is occasionally used as well.
2. "Scored a goal" (or "scored"). Three in one game is a "hat trick". Occasionally for two in a game I've heard Brits say "scored a brace".
3. We tend to call that "ball handling", or sometimes "possession".
4. I don't think we have just one word for that. I do hear "dangerous" used a lot, particularly with respect to a certain area a player is said to be dangerous in (for instance, Gareth Bale is particularly dangerous at the top of the box with the ball on his left foot). Someone who is good at making runs, getting open, and doing unpredictable things with the ball is said to be "creative". Someone who is just plain fast is said to have "pace" (I seriously hate that term).

Answer (score -1):

At a slight tangent, for a word that is 'special' in football is an English word that was first pushed into popular culture by football.

The noun 'bouncebackability' is originally believed to have been invented ( read used and as a result adopted) by Iain Dowie, the ex-player and now manager of Crystal Palace FC

The meaning 'The ability to bounce back'

The word was  promoted by Soccer AM, a cult Sky football show shown on Saturday mornings, in an attempt to see it into the Oxford Concise Dictionary; which it now does.

A possible use 'Crystal Palace have shown great bouncebackability against their opponants to really be back in this game

Not a direct answer to your question but an interesting use of British language in football ( British English as oppose to American English etc as Im unsure how far and wide it is used)

Comment: Iain Dowie was only 19 when David Shields wrote [what my high school coach used to call **"bouncebackability"**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bouncebackability+My+message%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), in [Heroes, 1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Shields) so Dowie obviously didn't "invent" the term.

Comment: No he appears to have not invented the term, nor the words bounce, back or ability. However is credited in the u.k as the man responsible for putting it into popular culture and and even been used by M.P's here in the UK.